# Issue with the Http Status in the template Blanco. Magento

Tags: magento, templates

I have installed the template Blanco in Magento 1.7.02 and I receive a “200 OK” status from the server, despite the URL still being invalid and the 404 page still being presented.

```
[root@host.shopmami.com] ~ >> curl -I http://www.almohadaspremama.com/aa
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I disable the template Blanco and obtain the correct status.

```
root@host.shopmami.com] ~ >> curl -I http://www.almohadaspremama.com/aa
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Please, anybody could help me to find the issue in the template?

Comment: How you have disabled the template?

Comment: If I disabled the templete obtain the correct status 404 for the invalids urls. But I need the template working